# How do I use a .Where to access values in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I just want any value where the id equals a "zj"

```
Dictionary<string,string> z = dm.UpdateAndReturnIdol(User, id, v).where(keys.equals("zj"));
```

Comment: What is `UpdateAndReturnIdol`?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#:" and the like. That's what we use tags for on [so].

Comment: Is the return type of `UpdateAndReturnIdol` a `Dictionary<string, string>` that you want to filter after the return? Or does it return a sequence of another type that you want to filter and also project into a dictionary?

Comment: @John, ok i wont do that in the future

Comment: your question needs more information, unless you need someone with psychic debugging skills

Comment: @Anthony, yes the return type is dictstringstring

Comment: Your question is currently very unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I agree, hard to understand.  It looks like you want to query a dictionary using where, but then the result wouldn't be a dictionary unless it's a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the return type is `Dictionary<string, string>` then you can just look up the value, e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =  dm.UpdateAndReturnIdol(User, id, v);
string value = dictionary["zj"];
```

or if you don't know whether there will be an entry:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =  dm.UpdateAndReturnIdol(User, id, v);
string value;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("zj", out value))
{
    // Use the value
}
```

There's no need to use `Where` here - the whole *point* of a dictionary is that you can look up by key efficiently... and there can only be one value per key, so there's no need to get a *sequence* of values.

Comment: Yeah, I too missed the obvious. The only context where `.Where` makes sense against the key is if the user was going for partial or fuzzy matching. If so, (a) it's probably a misuse of the dictionary, but (b) `Where` makes sense. Otherwise... no.

Comment: Love the fact that as soon as Jon Skeet posts his answer, every other answer goes away

Comment: @OskarKjellin, those are Jon Skeet Facts. Competing answers delete themselves out of a sense of justice (plus... erm, they were simply unhelpful in this case).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I know, wasn't arguing with the fact that it happened. This answer was the only good one